# SSRS Sparkline Render Issue in Matrix

Tags: reporting-services

Have used Sparkline in Matrix many times with no issue, now working for a new company and cannot get them to render correctly at all. They work great in VS. When deployed the matrix cell renders the row data for each column but within the cell it also renders the sparkline for all rows. so there are multiple sparklines in one cell each representing a different row, and this is repeated in each row of the report. using SQL 2008R2 VS2010, IE11. In chrome it does render only one sparkline per row but the formatting is OFF and I always make my users use IE in any case.

I have searched a lot for a solution and found nothing of help.

This is a really cool feature in SSRS and I am really keen to continue to use it as it provides a rich user experience for visualising raw numbers.

Any help would be awesome :)
[Report viewed via IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PszUj.png)

Comment: SAME HAPPENS WITH MULTIPLE GRAPHS

I did manage to get the graphs to behave by changing the "User Agent string" 

TO: "internet Explorer 6" via IE11 Developer tools

but this is not a solution, it just says to me that there is an issue with rendering in IE11 ...




Has anyone ever solved this issue ??

Comment: this poet describes the problem by no solution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e511f298-2828-4783-b17f-3c38f778f34f/duplication-of-charts-in-published-ssrs-2012-reports?forum=sqlreportingservices